# Looping through a complex php array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( 
    [event_title] => Registration
    [event_id] => 17
    [location_id] => 113
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [event_title] => Sunday Collections
    [event_id] => 67
    [location_id] => 113
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [event_title] => School Tuition
    [event_id] => 68
    [location_id] => 113
  )
)
```

Can anyone tell me how to extract `event_title`, `event_id` and `location_id` from this array? I want to display this in the form of a table actually.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Please show us the code you've created, so we can find out whats wrong with it.

Comment: Use 1 loop like `for ($x = 0; $x < count($myArray); $x++)` then you can access the values at `$myArray[$x]['event_title']`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display it in a table, you can do this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Event Title</th>
    <th>Event ID</th>
    <th>Location ID</th>
  </tr>
<?php foreach($array as $item): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['event_title'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['event_id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['location_id'] ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

The array is very **simple** in fact.

```
foreach($array as $item) {

    $event_title = $item['event_title'];
    $event_id = $item['event_id'];
    $location_id = $item['location_id'];    

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<table><?php
    foreach($array as $arr) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.
            $arr['event_title'].
            '</td><td>'.
            $arr['event_id'].
            '</td><td>'.
            $arr['location_id'].
            '</td></tr>'.PHP_EOL;
     }
?></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr as $event){
    echo $event["event_title"] . "\t" . $event["event_id"] . "\t". $event["location_id"] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
  ...
  echo "<td>{$row['event_title']}</td>";
  ...
}
```